# Button changing of state programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im really having a problem with my image with button frame, 
What I want is: 
1. When it is selected it will have a checkmark
2. When the view is dismissed then returned back to the previous screen it will still have the check in the image selected 
3. When I tap the selected image or another image it will remove the checkmark.

I was able to do it but I'm having problem with the setting of image:

What I want is this:

[image]

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[myButton setEnabled:NO];
```

But this is the function I needed:

[image]

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
[myButton setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setSelected:YES];
```

Here is the code below(If there is something wrong with what I'm doing please tell me, Thanks):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    // Create view
    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(column*140+24, row*150+10, 100, 100);
        [myButton setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.tag = i; 
        NSLog(@"%i",i);

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger selectedImageSlot1 = [prefs integerForKey:@"selected1"];

        if ( selectedImageSlot1 == i){
            [self turnButtonToSelected];
        } 

        [view addSubview:myButton];

        if (column == 6) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, (row+1) * 150 + 10)];
}

- (void)turnButtonToSelected
{       UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [myButton setEnabled:NO];
}
- (void)highlightButton:(UIButton *)a {
    //[self turnButtonToSelected];    
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    myButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:myButton.tag];

    if (myButton.selected) {

        [sender setSelected:NO];

    }else {

        UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
        [sender setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }


    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:myButton.tag forKey:@"slot1"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myButton.tag forKey:@"selected1"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

Or is there a way to forcefully make a button enabled whenever it is disabled when tapped also?

Comment: Have you tried to change the button's state between `UIControlStateNormal` & `UIControlStateSelected`?

Comment: yes, I have I don't know why it looks like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just tried this on a different approach.

For me it works just fine and achieves your effect.

Let me know if you need further explanation or the entire Xcode project.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //button 1
    UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 80);
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5359.JPG"];
    [imageButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //button 2
    UIButton *imageButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    imageButton2.frame = CGRectMake(180, 50, 100, 80);
    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5355.JPG"];
    [imageButton2 setBackgroundImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self.view addSubview:imageButton];
    [self.view addSubview:imageButton2];
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    //NSLog(@"Button clicked! %@", button);

    UIImage *checkmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    UIImage *empty = nil;

    //NSLog(@"Imageview: %d", button.imageView.tag);
    if (button.imageView.tag == 0)
    {
        [button setImage:checkmarkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.imageView.tag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:empty forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.imageView.tag = 0;
    }
}
```

Best, Chris

**Update: I have updated the code. Here is the entire ViewController. Note: I would solve this using coreData to store the current index. The following code is not the best to solve this issue but is based on your initial code!**

```
//
//  SOViewController.m
//  SOImageOverlay
//
//  Created by Chris on 24.07.12.
//

#import "SOViewController.h"

@interface SOViewController ()

@end


#define CHECKMARK_IMAGE @"check.png"

@implementation SOViewController

@synthesize buttons = _buttons;

#pragma mark - Custom getter
- (NSMutableArray*)buttons
{
    if (_buttons == nil)
        _buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return _buttons;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:CHECKMARK_IMAGE];
//    UIButton *myButton = 
//    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    // Create view
//    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {

        /*UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(column*140+24, row*150+10, 100, 100);
        [myButton setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.tag = i; 
        NSLog(@"%i",i);*/

        UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        if (i == 0)
        {
            UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5359.JPG"];
            imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 80);
            [imageButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (i == 1)
         {
             UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5355.JPG"];
             imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(180, 50, 100, 80);
             [imageButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }

        [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger selectedImageSlot1 = [prefs integerForKey:@"selected1"];

        if ( selectedImageSlot1 == i){
            [self turnButtonToSelected:imageButton];
        } 

        [self.view addSubview:imageButton];

        //adding current button into buttons array
        [self.buttons addObject:imageButton];

        if (column == 6) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    //[view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, (row+1) * 150 + 10)];


//    //button 1
//    UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 80);
//    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5359.JPG"];
//    [imageButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//    
//    //button 2
//    UIButton *imageButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    imageButton2.frame = CGRectMake(180, 50, 100, 80);
//    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC_5355.JPG"];
//    [imageButton2 setBackgroundImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [imageButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//
//    [self.view addSubview:imageButton];
//    [self.view addSubview:imageButton2];
}

//- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
//{
//    //NSLog(@"Button clicked! %@", button);
//    
//    UIImage *checkmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
//    UIImage *empty = nil;
//    
//    //NSLog(@"Imageview: %d", button.imageView.tag);
//    if (button.imageView.tag == 0)
//    {
//        [button setImage:checkmarkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//        button.imageView.tag = 1;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        [button setImage:empty forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//        button.imageView.tag = 0;
//    }
//}



// code from stackoverflow
// ------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)turnButtonToSelected:(UIButton*)button
{       
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:CHECKMARK_IMAGE];

    //UIButton *myButton = button; //just to use the copied code
    button.selected = YES;
    [button setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];


//    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//    [myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
//    [myButton setEnabled:NO];
}
- (void)highlightButton:(UIButton *)a {
    //[self turnButtonToSelected];    
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    //I have removed this line... due to the fact that I don't want to 
    //implement your arrays.
    //self.selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:myButton.tag];

    //deselecting all
    for (UIButton *button in self.buttons)
    {
        button.selected = NO;
        //[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if (myButton.selected) {

        [sender setSelected:NO];

    }else {

        UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:CHECKMARK_IMAGE];
        [sender setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }


//    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//    [prefs setInteger:myButton.tag forKey:@"slot1"];


    //getting index of button in array
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger foundIndex = -1;
    for (UIButton *button in self.buttons)
    {
        if (button == myButton)
        {
            foundIndex = index;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (foundIndex >= 0)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:foundIndex forKey:@"selected1"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
   // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
// ------------------------------------------------------------


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}



- (IBAction)closeButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Each `UIView` (and derived classes) in objective-c contain a `tag` attribute. Normally it is used when you, for example, create a new view in storyboard, you can access this element by the tag. Often it is used to store particular information. You can also use `.accessibleIdentifier` to store if it is `selected` or not. However, you need to store the information on the element itself and the `tag` attribute is a way to achieve this. :)

Comment: I have done the overlaping part, but what i need is when an image is selected then when i select another image it will remove the other one.

Comment: Alright, I'll dig into this. First of all: What is `myButton`? A property?

Comment: Okay, then synthesize it and use it as `self.myButton`. However, what do you want exactly to achieve? I guess the user should select an avatar or something like that? Could you give us a little bit more code?

Comment: Okay... I think now I understand your issue. Your problem is related to the modal view. You want to restore the selected-condition when the user opens the modal view again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14336/discussion-between-chris-and-kobe-o4)

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this.

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
**[myButton setSelected:NO];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];**


UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AGIPC-Checkmark-iPhone.png"];
**[myButton setSelected:YES];
[myButton setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];**
```

In the later part of code, you are setting the state of the button to "selected" but in the upper code, you haven't. Rather, you have disabled the button. Try the above code which I have provided. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just add you chekedImage as a subview on top of the button when user clicks the button

```
UIImage *button = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.png"];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//add target button clicked 


-(void)buttonClicked : (id)sender{
    if(toogleSwitch){
       [button addSubview:checkedimageView]; // Just the checked image icon
    }
    else{
       [imageview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

What you are trying to do will only work when you have 
resources of two types for all your images.
1) The image itself
2) Image with checked box as transparent layer.

Comment: `UIButton` supports two images. The `backgroundImage` and the `image` property. So it is not necessary to add an additional layer on top.

Comment: Thanks for the information ... I will keep that in mind in future :)